# how to use components of one project in another in angular 2

Tags: angular2-directives

I have two angular 2 projects 
1) Project-A
2) Project-B
and I want to use some of the components of project-A in Project-B page and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You may create an npm package to use your component as a module in your project. More info [here](https://codeburst.io/https-chidume-nnamdi-com-npm-module-in-typescript-12b3b22f0724).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mono repo pattern, this will solve you the dependency peoblems for example when you update the packages you will update the project with the breacking changes. Another aproach can be npm packages as sugested before but if you have breaking changes in packages from a version to another version you can schedule the updates for projects.

Comment: Thank you, I Created a shared feature module and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I created a shared featured module and I achieved my requirement.
for reference click here

https://plnkr.co/edit/YAObDCptFRdEBkFvDSJh?p=preview`here`

https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/